# I want to send packet with Scapy and it send packet normally, but they come back without an answer

Tags: python, scapy, arp, spoofing

This part of the code should find the MAC address of the target using its IP address.

```
def get_MAC(ip):
    pkt_Ether = scapy.Ether(dst='ff:ff:ff:ff:ff')
    pkt_ARP = scapy.ARP(pdst=ip)
    packet = pkt_ARP / pkt_Ether
    ans, unans = scapy.srp(packet, timeout=1, verbose=False) [0]
    ans[0][1][ARP].hwsrc = target_mac
    return target_mac
```

With the MAC address of the target, it should then send a packet to the target and the router but I don't know why it's not working.

```
def spoof(target_ip, spoof_ip):
    target_mac = get_MAC(target_ip)
    packet = scapy.ARP(op=2, pdst=target_ip, hwdst=target_mac, psrc=spoof_ip)
    scapy.srp(packet, verbose=False)
```

I tried to use Python3 by adapting the program to be executed, but it sends the packets and they return without a response.

If someone can help me...